# Is saying Christ haram

Tags: halal-haram, christianity

I was listing to something and they said Christ in the song and I was listening to the lyrics so I said it too but my intention wasn’t to call for help I was just singing the lyrics is it haram

Answer (score 0):

It is not haram to mention the name of Christ. Christ is English for the Messiah. The Quran confirms that he is the Messiah, and that we should honour all prophets.

I don't know what the song said. Some Christian text may be accepteble and some are not. You may link to the lyrics or cite if you would like to have further information.

Comment: The lyrics were Even the blind can see Christ

Comment: The text may refer to Mark 10:46ff, an account on the prophet Jesus (p b.u.h) which is acceptable. In contrast, if "Christ" is used for what is attributed to God the text must not be sung.

Answer (score 0):

**No,** if you didn't mean to refer to him as God.

And if you think you have said something wrong, the door of repentance is always open. Allah is the greatest forgiver.

*May Allah bless you and keep you away from haram music.*

Comment: Inshallah thank you